# Readable Django ajax request errors

Tags: ajax, django

What is the best way to have readable ajax views errors in Django?

I can read them in Chrome's  Response tab but only as plain text and a lot of information that is available on Django's standard error page is missing.

I have found the Django-Ajaxerror and sort of fixed it to run under Windows but it still doesn't work. How does everybody manage this problem in Django world?

Comment: What do you mean by readable ajax views errors ? Plain/text or json (since you're talking about ajax) ? 
I'm guessing you are submiting your form through ajax and expect some kind of JSON dict back if there were errors ?

Comment: Just load the ajax view in the browser. You'll see the standard Django error page then.

Comment: Chris, but the context will be different if I directly call the view in the browser.